# index() function is acting strangely in my code

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the index of a non integer from a list, however when running the script for different values I get different indexes each time!
Am I using index() not as intended? I'd appreciate any help.

```
m = [1, 2, '.', 3]
pos = int()
for y in m:
    if y != int():
        pos = m.index(y)
print(pos)
```

For this particular list the output prints "3", instead of the wanted "2"

Comment: `if y != int():` is checking if `y != 0`

Comment: ohhh, such a stupid mistake. Was playing with int() for half an hour thinking that it's just empty. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the type of y and you do not need to initialize pos as an int

```
m = [1, 2, '.', 3]
for y in m:
    if not isinstance(y, int):
        pos = m.index(y)
print(pos)
```

Comment: Try to avoid checking `if type(object) == desired_type`. Instead, use `if isinstance(object, desired_type)`. The former does not support inheritance or subclassing

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Thanks for the feedback. I fixed it now

Comment: Thanks for your time!
I've already tryied fixing it with replacing ```if y ==str(y):``` but your answer is better and I shall use it for further coding. Cheers!

Comment: You can apply to seeing if its a string too, using ```isinstance(y, str)```